# SumIf value always returns as 0 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I am using the `SumIf` function to add up all the cells that contain the string `dailyTotal` to the left of them. I then set a cell `C29` on the `Macros` sheet to that value and compare it to a number to see what code executes next. I have values in the E column cells, but the value always returns as 0.

Code:

```
dailyTotal = "Daily Total:"
Dim totalHours As Double
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Totals!E11:E100")
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng.Cells
  With Sheets("Totals")
    Sheets("Macros").Range("C29").Formula = Application.SumIf(cell.Offset(, -1), dailyTotal, "")
    Sheets("Macros").Range("C29") = totalHours
  End With
Next cell

' check if command is applicable
If totalHours > 4 Then
```

Comment: The SUMIF formula is wrong: SUM(RANGE,CRITERIA,[RANGE_TO_SUM]).  You want to use the entire range not an individual cell.  And you have two criteria, the string `"Daily Total:"` and `""`  Could you show some test data and expected outcome?

Comment: Adjusted to a comment as this is only partial: Remove this line: "Sheets("Macros").Range("C29") = totalHours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be after this

```
Dim totalHours As Double
Dim dailyTotal As String: dailyTotal = "Daily Total:"
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Totals!E11:E100")

totalHours = Application.SumIf(rng.Offset(, -1), dailyTotal, rng)
Sheets("Macros").Range("C29") = totalHours

' check if command is applicable
If totalHours > 4 Then ...
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Apparently I was over complicating it by looping through all the cells instead of just the range.